# Выполнение цикла до определенного этапа

Tags: php

Есть число, например 75. 
Читаем это число задом наперед  - 57.

57 + 75 = 132.
Читаем с конца - 231.

231 + 132 = 363.
Читаем с конца 363.

Прекращаем выполнение цикла и выводим сколько раз выполнился цикл.

Что я делаю не так?

```
$text = "75";
$text = mb_strtolower($text);
$text1 = str_replace(" ","",$text);

function strrev_enc($text2) {
  $text2 = strrev($text2);
  return $text2;
}

$text2 = strrev_enc($text1);

$p=0;
for($text = 75; $text1 != $text2; $text = $text1+$text2) {
  $p++;
}
```

Comment: Код `$text = mb_strtolower($text);
$text1 = str_replace(" ","",$text);

function strrev_enc($text2) {
  $text2 = strrev($text2);
  return $text2;
}

$text2 = strrev_enc($text1);` не имеет ни малейшего смысла.

Comment: @Mike голова кипит уже.. сообразить не могу((

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы пишите на php так, как будто это функциональный язык. А он императивный ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 57; // Число
$i = 0;    // Счётчик
while ($str != strrev($str)) {
    $str = intval($str) + intval(strrev($str)); // Суммируем число и его реверс
    $i++;
}
echo $i;
```

*P.S. Мне начинают нравиться Ваши задачки :)*

Comment: а почему выведет 132 363 ? возмите число 75, и должно вывести 2, так как третий раз число задом наперед читается так же как и предыдущее

Comment: @Денис, поправил.